# How to get Keil Trace to work on stm32f4 for debugging?

Tags: arm, debugging, keil, st

I'm using stmf429-disc board with Keil 5.I've enabled trace check in hardware debug's trace window and have set trace clock to 168MHz which is the core clock freq. Also enabled the port 31 for rtx trace and 0 for for user trace. When I start debugging the debug's os event viewer doesn't update although "System and Thread Viewer" is updating as expected(I'm running an OS). Also ITM_sendchar(char) function doesn't send anything apparently.

Comment: Are you sure trace clock should be equal to core clock? Seems a bit on the high side if you're not using a dedicated capture device (but I've not checked the datasheet)

Comment: Yes, it is also noted on keil site notes. eg. in "apnt_230__MDK V5.10 Lab for the STM32F4 Discovery Board"